# TypeORM find where conditions AND OR chaining

Tags: typescript, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I'm trying to compose query with Repository find and I don't seem to find a solution for my query.
I am aware this is possible with query builder or with Raw() conditions, but I would like to use Repository find if possible.

Where condition I am trying to achieve is **field1 = 'string' *AND* (field2 IS NULL *OR* field2 >= Date())**.

Currently the only solution that works for me is:

```
where: [
 { param1: 'string', field2: IsNull() },
 { param1: 'string', field2: MoreThenOrEqual(new Date() ) }
]
```

But this would traslate to **(field1 = 'string' AND field2 IS NULL) OR (field1 = 'string' OR field2 >= Date())**

I tried something like:

```
where: [
 { param1: 'string', field2: ( IsNull() || MoreThenOrEqual(new Date() ) ) }
]
```

But I could make it work. Does anyone know if my original where condition could be done without changing query?

FYI: I'm using Typescript with TypeORM.

**Edit 1.**
Based on request from comments I'm posting my current implementation using queryBuilder (just the where condition):

```
.where('param1 = :var1', {va1: 'string'})
.andWhere(new Brackets(query => {
 query.where('field2 IS NULL')
  .orWhere('field3 >= NOW()::DATE')
})
```

Comment: Why don't you use raw query and bind parameters?

Comment: @glinda93 like I wrote in the question I'm aware that is one way of doing it, but it's not the most clear way. I'm wanna know if there is a way of doing it without changing desired query, using Raw() or using query builder for it. Hope I have answered your question.

Comment: Imo, using array of `where`s and multiple logic operations of typeorm operators is way less intuitive than using raw query and binding parameters.

Comment: I am trying to do the same but apparently at the moment there's no such a feature. The only way to do it with a find is to repeat your code and use some tricks.

Answer (score 7):

There is a [Brackets](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/test/functional/query-builder/brackets/query-builder-brackets.ts) in typeorm

Usage:

```
const sql = await connection
                    .createQueryBuilder(User, "user")
                    .where("user.isAdmin = :isAdmin", { isAdmin: true })
                    .orWhere(
                        new Brackets((qb) => {
                            qb.where("user.firstName = :firstName1", {
                                firstName1: "Hello",
                            }).andWhere("user.lastName = :lastName1", {
                                lastName1: "Mars",
                            })
                        }),
                    )
                    .orWhere(
                        new Brackets((qb) => {
                            qb.where("user.firstName = :firstName2", {
                                firstName2: "Hello",
                            }).andWhere("user.lastName = :lastName2", {
                                lastName2: "Earth",
                            })
                        }),
                    )
```

Comment: This is not a solution I was looking for. This is query made using queryBuilder and not Repository find. I am aware of Brackets and in the end I used (currently queryBuilder + Brackets) for the solution. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @korxz Can you share your solution then?

Comment: Sure can.
I will post it in the original post.