# How to make Typeorm QueryBuilder work for AND and OR inside AND operators?

Tags: typescript, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

Hi I have written the following Typeform Querybuilder code ...

```
queryBuilder.andWhere('tdm.type =:type', { type: filters.type })
    queryBuilder.andWhere('tdm.form =:form', { form: filters.formId })

    if (filters.orLeadId && filters.orSupportId) {
      queryBuilder.andWhere(subQb => {
        subQb.where('tdm.leadId = :lead', { lead: filters.orLeadId }),
          subQb.orWhere('tdm.supportId = :support', {
            support: filters.orSupportId,
          })
      })
    }
```

But it results in neglecting the andWhere Operators and results in the following query

```sql
SELECT "tdm"."id" AS "tdm_id", "tdm"."form_id" AS "tdm_form_id" FROM "tdm" "tdm" WHERE "tdm"."lead_id" = $1 OR "tdm"."support_id" = $2
```

Can anyone help me to get the above code right please!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `new Brackets` will have to be used here so the clause containing the two conditions to be *OR'ed* are inside the brackets after `AND` as it would be when writing in plain SQL

```
queryBuilder
  .andWhere('tdm.type =:type', { type: filters.type })
  .andWhere('tdm.form =:form', { form: filters.formId })

  if (filters.orLeadId && filters.orSupportId) {
    queryBuilder.andWhere(
      new Brackets(subQb => {
        subQb
          .where('tdm.leadId = :lead', { lead: filters.orLeadId })
          .orWhere('tdm.supportId = :support', { support: filters.orSupportId })
      })
    )
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, this answers will be helpful to others

Answer (score 1):

I refactored the code as follows

```
 if (filters.orLeadId && filters.orSupportId) {
      queryBuilder.andWhere(
        new Brackets(subQb => {
          subQb
            .where('tdm.leadId = :lead', { lead: filters.orLeadId })
            .orWhere('tdm.supportId = :support', {
              support: filters.orSupportId,
            })
        })
      )
```

I followed [TypeORM find where conditions AND OR chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71783696/typeorm-find-where-conditions-and-or-chaining?rq=1) and its working like a charm

Comment: Ah you beat me to it :p Kudos on finding the answer yourself and posting it here!