# Typeorm top level and operator without using querybuilder

Tags: typeorm

How could I achieve the following query using TypeORM without the QueryBuilder. I know I could do this with .andWhere(), but will I be able to do this with just .find()

```
where (
  ("User"."name" ilike $1 or "User"."email" ilike $5) 
  and "User"."organizationId" in ($17, $18, $19)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this can't be achieved with repository pattern.
I have asked same questions here: [TypeORM find where conditions AND OR chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71783696/typeorm-find-where-conditions-and-or-chaining)

You can check there what did I use for the solution.